# Print an array with lists as elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

I started creating an array, then i referenced its element with lists. Now I want to print the entire array (this is: all the lists on the array), i created a function "show" and "show array" but always print the last element of the array

IN:

```
class Test:
    pass

def read(v, r):
    n = len(v)
    for i in range(0, n):
        v[i] = r
        v[i].number= 5+i
        v[i].name = i*2
        v[i].author = i+6
        v[i].genre = i*3
        v[i].quantity = i+2


def show_array(v):
    n = len(v)
    for i in range(0, n):
        show(v[i])


def show(reg):
    print(reg.number, end=' ; ')
    print(reg.name, end=' ; ')
    print(reg.author, end=' ; ')
    print(reg.genre, end=' ; ')
    print(reg.quantity)

def menu():

    v = 2 * [None]


    t= Test()
    read(v, t)

    show_array(v)


menu()
```

OUT:

```
6 ; 2 ;  7 ;  3 ;  3
6 ; 2 ;  7 ;  3 ;  3
```

Comment: FWIW, your "array" `v` is a list, so calling it an [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is a bit confusing.

Comment: Pass `r=Test` and say `v[i] = r()` to create a new instance of `Test`

Comment: I did what you say Peter and worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are showing all elements of the array. They are all pointing to the *same object* so when you alter the object in your `read` loop, you change the object everywhere. You need to create a new `Test` object for each place in your array.

Comment: You were right, I delete "t = Test()" and in "for" of "read" I put "v[i] = Test()" directly and worked :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because this is only one t.
First value is always coverd by last value.

You can write "print (v[i].name)" in "for" of "read()" and you can see the diffrence.
You should create a new t.

Comment: I added a print in "read()" but seems ok. OUT: 5; 0; 6; 0; 2
6; 2; 7; 3; 3

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python expert but u can try to make use of isinstance() this may help you to print all the values of a specified list by comparing the array value with list.If it is a list then print that particular list elements.If it is not a list then print the normal array value.

https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/isinstance-function.html